# jQuery animate, not smooth

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, smoothing

do you have an idea, how the animated cats could move smoother?

It's stuttering and I don't know how to set it smoother.
jQuery.fx.interval isn't helping

http://christianhaller.com/jquery-animate-img.html

thx,
christian

Comment: Try pictures of snails... might be slower, but smoother.

Comment: tips: in the current state, you started moving the image when the white flash stopped; the animation would probably look slicker if you started moving the image when the white flash started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stuttering appears to be because of the easing, since you are moving the image a very small amount and small changes are obvious. Just set the `easing` parameter of the animation to `linear`.

Answer (score 7):

From the [CrossSlide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/) jQuery plugin developer:

> It also bears to mention that CSS and DOM force a script to round
>   position and size of images to integer
>   pixel values, for every frame of an
>   animation, not just keyframes. This
>   effectively makes it impossible to
>   achieve slow, smooth animations. If
>   you are experiencing this issue, my
>   only advice is to either make the
>   animation faster, do away with
>   diagonal panning and/or image zooming,
>   or switch to a different animation
>   technology.

I believe that applies here as well. Hope that helps.