# jQuery Animation Jump

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tumblr

The header to my tumblr page seems a bit jumpy when I attempted to animate its growth and shrinkage when it is no longer on the top of the page.

The webpage is [Tobacco Endeavors](http://tobaccoendeavors.tumblr.com/) and is a tumblr blog.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
            $("#abracadabra").fadeOut(500, function(){ 
                $("#header").animate({padding:"1.5em 0"}, 500);
            });
        } else {
            $("#abracadabra").fadeIn(500, function(){ 
                $("#header").animate({padding:"1em 0"}, 500);
            });
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Thanks a bunch guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll event could fire many times, you need to control concurrency with a flag, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.flag = true;                                         
    $(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
            if (window.flag) {
               window.flag = false;
               $("#abracadabra").fadeOut(500, function(){ 
                   $("#header").animate({padding:"1.5em 0"}, 500, function() {window.flag = true;});
               });
            }
        } else {
            if (window.flag) {
               window.flag = false;
               $("#abracadabra").fadeIn(500, function(){ 
                   $("#header").animate({padding:"1em 0"}, 500, function(){window.flag = true;});
               });
            }
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

**UPDATE**:

Updated a typo in code. Try new version above.

Answer (score 1):

`stop()` and `fadeTo()` can fix some strange issues sometimes :)

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ucecop/1/edit)*

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
            $("#abracadabra").stop().fadeTo(500,0, function(){ 
                $("#header").stop().animate({padding:"1.5em 0"}, 500);
            });
        } else {
            $("#abracadabra").stop().fadeTo(500,1, function(){ 
                $("#header").stop().animate({padding:"1em 0"}, 500);
            }); 
        }
});
```

about your issue:

from the DOCS:

> The .fadeOut() method animates the opacity of the matched elements. Once the opacity reaches 0, the display style property is set to none, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

causing jumpy result. On the other hand **fadeTo()** method

> With duration set to 0, this method just changes the opacity CSS property, so .fadeTo(0, opacity) is the same as .css('opacity', opacity).

and as you can see affecting nicely *the layout of the page.*

Answer (score 0):

See [jQuery animate, not smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696524/jquery-animate-not-smooth)

> ..Just set the easing parameter of the animation to linear.

There are also plugins people have made as alternatives if you feel inclined.

Comment: how would I go about doing that? is that a CSS thing or a jQuery thing?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery/JavaScript animations can be jumpy at times, and can also depend on an individuals personal hardware setup. What I like to do for animations is make a css class that has a transition, and the add the class. Additionally, make another css class that has the opposite transition, and add that one to animate out. This works pretty well, and if i'm not mistaken, provides increased browser compatibility.